# accessing Facebook notifications, messages, etc

Tags: facebook, command-line

I am trying to build a command line tool or a text-only interface to use Facebook for personal use. I wish to know if it would be possible to access a user's notifications, requests, messages, etc through python, c++, shel scripts or HTML. if it is, It would be great if I could be pointed to a proper resource where i could get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great idea, and is entirely possible with the Facebook Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). With the API, you can do GET, POST and DELETE requests to view, update and remove posts, view news feed stories, read inbox etc. Read through the documentation to see what's available.

Before you start however, you should think about how to get an access token for the user, as you'll need this for all non-trivial Graph API requests. An access token is granted once a user grants your app permissions, and this can only happen through a pop-up dialog in a browser or mobile app. As a result, your users will need to authenticate your app through a browser first, before they can use the command line tool. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for information on the authentication process.